# Unable to apply date range in stats field in SOLR

Tags: solr

I need to create pivot data by applying filter of two fields i.e city and date range.
Able to filter data by cities and date range but filter is not applying on stats field.
Following is the Solr query that i'm using :

select?&fq={!tag=f1}city:(%221000%20OAKS%22)&facet=true&facet.query=true&facet.query={!tag=queryOne}datadate:[2015-01-01%20TO%202015-12-31]&facet.query={!tag=queryTwo}datadate:[2014-01-01%20TO%202014-12-31]&stats=true&stats.field={!tag=a1%20sum=true%20key=charge1}charge&stats.field={!tag=a2%20sum=true%20key=spend1}spend&facet.pivot={!query=queryOne%20key=c1%20stats=a1}city&facet.pivot={!query=queryTwo%20stats=a2%20key=c2}city&facet=on&indent=on&wt=json&rows=0&q=*:*

Actual Result :
[image]

As you can see, the sum remains same (i.e 2348) regardless of what datadate i m giving in queryone & querytwo tags.
It appears that datadate filters is not having any effect on stats field.
Can anyone please explain what is happening here as i'm pretty new to this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which Solr version are you using?

Comment: Using Solr-6.1.0

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `StatsComponent` & `FacetComponent` are not in perfect integration with each other. The following Solr Jira comprises your use-case: [SOLR-6348](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-6348).

But nevertheless there is work-around for your use-case via [JSON Facet API](http://yonik.com/json-facet-api/). Here is facet parameter which solves your particular use-case:

```
{
  "date_range": {
    "type": "range",
    "field": "datadate_dt",
    "start": "2014-01-01T00:00:00Z",
    "end": "2016-01-01T00:00:00Z",
    "gap": "%2B1YEAR",
    "facet": {
      "cities_and_spends": {
        "type": "terms",
        "field": "city_s",
        "facet": {"sum_of_spend": "sum(spend_d)"}
      },
      "cities_and_charges": {
        "type": "terms",
        "field": "city_s",
        "facet": {"sum_of_spend": "sum(charge_d)"}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Hence the overall GET request would look like:

```
.../select?indent=on&q=*:*&fq=city:(%221000%20OAKS%22)&rows=0&wt=json&json.facet={%20%22date_range%22:%20{%20%22type%22:%20%22range%22,%20%22field%22:%20%22datadate_dt%22,%20%22start%22:%20%222014-01-01T00:00:00Z%22,%20%22end%22:%20%222016-01-01T00:00:00Z%22,%20%22gap%22:%20%22%2B1YEAR%22,%20%22facet%22:%20{%20%22cities_and_spends%22:%20{%20%22type%22:%20%22terms%22,%20%22field%22:%20%22city_s%22,%20%22facet%22:%20{%22sum_of_spend%22:%20%22sum(spend_d)%22}%20},%20%22cities_and_charges%22:%20{%20%22type%22:%20%22terms%22,%20%22field%22:%20%22city_s%22,%20%22facet%22:%20{%22sum_of_spend%22:%20%22sum(charge_d)%22}%20}%20}%20}%20}
```